# Событие удаление DOM объекта. Как обработать? Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, dom, chrome-extension

Есть DOM-объект, таблица:

```
table_body=document.getElementsByClassName(....).[0];
```

У этого объекта есть childnodes - элементы таблицы.
По одному их них я симулирую клик. 
Идёт отправка на сайт, приходит ответ и в таблице больше нет этого элемента.

Вопрос:
Как "грамотно", обработать это?
Мне нужно потом table_body.length после всех этих событий!
Замучился, ужас!!! Помогите!

```
var market_hist = document.getElementsByClassName('market_hist')[0];
var allord_table_body;
allord_table_body=GetTableOfOrdersFromDom(market_hist); //просто ищет таблицу.
.......
RemoveOneElement(0,market_hist) //удаляем нулевой элемент таблицы
.....

function RemoveOneElement(num ,market_hist)
{
   allord_table_body=GetTableOfOrdersFromDom(market_hist); //просто ищет таблицу.  
   //код проверки...

  simulateClick(allord_table_body[i+1].childNodes[5].childNodes[0]);
.....
```

Дальше я пытаюсь сделать так:
Ставлю обработчик события "DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument"

```
allord_table_body[i+1].childNodes[5].childNodes[0].addEventListener("DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument", function() {    
        sendMessage("sleep");
    });
```

Отправляю в background script сообщение слип. А оттуда уже обратное сообщение, спустя 7 секунд.
Получается слегка криво!

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (request.messagefrombackground=="continue") //SLEEP сработала, продолжаем
    {
        var market_hist = document.getElementsByClassName('market_hist')[0];
        var allord_table_body;
        alert("Passes 18 sec");
        //var nnn3=0;
         allord_table_body=GetTableOfOrdersFromDom(market_hist);
        alert(message.greeting+" "+ allord_table_body.length-1 );
    }


});
```

allord_table_body[i+1] - у этого DOM объекта childNodes До конца не обработаны!!!
В отладчике это видно

[image: Из отладчика]

Как бы, что это такое, почему так!? Как правильно сделать?
Потому что остальные функции у меня работают после события 
window.onload
И этот дом объект выглядит вот так:
[image: После полной обработки]

Comment: *allord_table_body[i+1] - у этого DOM объекта childNodes До конца не обработаны!!!* Что значит до конца не обработаны?

Comment: Добавил картинку. После загрузки страницы - дом объект выглядит совсем по-другому.
И child и ChildNode одинаковые.